# Customize TOC, center align and italics in memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, memoir, italic

I would like to customize my TOC so that titles are centred and *italicized* while in the `\frontmatter`, like in the following picture:

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,a5paper,extrafontsizes, draft, showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\begin{document}
        \frontmatter
        \tableofcontents*
        \chapter{Apresentação}
        \chapter{Dedicatória}
        \chapter{Agradecimentos}
        \chapter{Introdução}
        \mainmatter
        \chapter{Preparação}
        \chapter{Conhecimento}
        \chapter{Influências}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, in my opinion, this does not look nice!

Comment: Me too!
But I am just editing the book and the author would want to take a look in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to have two different layouts for the same thing - `\chapter`s - you'll have to insert content into the ToC at specific times so the formatting occurs dynamically.

Below I've patched `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` to do exactly that. Each command inserts something specific into the ToC. `\frontmatter` updates `\cftchapterfont` by appending to it a font change (`\itshape`) as well as centering it (via `\hfill`). The reason for a single `\hfill` centering the content is because the typical leader that *follows* a chapter entry already adds a rubber fill. As such, adding one *before* centres it. A small adjustment has to be made to centre it perfectly, as there is no page number on the left of the entry. We merely add a blank page entry to achieve this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}
\makeatletter
\let\oldcftchapterfont\cftchapterfont% Save ToC-related chapter entry font
\g@addto@macro\frontmatter{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{% Update chapter entry font
    \protect\g@addto@macro\protect\cftchapterfont{\protect\cftchapterformatpnum{}\hfill\itshape}%
  }%
}

\g@addto@macro\mainmatter{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{% Restore chapter entry font
    \let\protect\cftchapterfont\protect\oldcftchapterfont%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Apresentação}
\chapter{Dedicatória}
\chapter{Agradecimentos}
\chapter{Introdução}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Preparação}
\chapter{Conhecimento}
\chapter{Influências}

\end{document}
```

---

The above solution can be modified slightly to obtain a centred-left alignment as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}
\makeatletter
\let\oldcftchapterfont\cftchapterfont% Save ToC-related chapter entry font
\g@addto@macro\frontmatter{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{% Update chapter entry font
    \protect\g@addto@macro\protect\cftchapterfont{\protect\cftchapterformatpnum{}\hfill\itshape
    \protect\eqmakebox[tocfm][l]}%
  }%
}

\g@addto@macro\mainmatter{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{% Restore chapter entry font
    \let\protect\cftchapterfont\protect\oldcftchapterfont%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Apresentação}
\chapter{Dedicatória}
\chapter{Agradecimentos}
\chapter{Introdução}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Preparação}
\chapter{Conhecimento}
\chapter{Influências}

\end{document}
```

I've inserted a `\eqmakebox[tocfm][l]` in front of every `toc` entry that forms part of the `f`ront `m`atter. Since [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) surrounds its ToC entries with braces, `\eqmakebox` will pick this up as a complete argument, `l`eft-aligning each entry while also centering it as before.

[`eqparbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<pos>]{<stuff>}` aligns all `<stuff>` with the same `<tag>` using `<pos>`.

Comment: Is there a way to have them on the same identation?
Like the picture : [http://tinyurl.com/jeabgev]

Comment: @Adriano: See the updated answer.